# react-helmet-async returns empty string if am fetching data from an api

Tags: html, reactjs, meta-tags, react-helmet

am fetching data from an api and I want some of whose data's content to be in meta tags inside of Helmet(react-helmet-async), however it returns empty string no matter what. if I statically write some text, its okay, its working on title too, but its not working on og tags

```
 <Helmet>
       
      <meta property="og:type"          content="WebSite" />
   
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="440924728203663"/>
    <meta  property='og:title'  content={exactNews.title}/>
    <meta property="og:url" content={window.location.href}/>
    <meta property="og:description" content=""></meta>
    <meta property="og:image" content={exactNews.title ? `https://khulo.gov.ge/${exactNews.img}` :   "alt"}/>
       
       
    
       <title>
        { language == 1 ? exactNews.geo.title ? exactNews.geo.title :  "" : ""}
        { language == 2 ? exactNews.eng.title ? exactNews.eng.title :  "" : ""}
       </title>


       


      </Helmet>
```

,like I said - title is working, but og tags are empty(see picture below)

[image]

I guess its because of async nature of this library? any tips on how to make it work? I tried rendering  using ternery operator but nothing.